# i saw musical symbol in html plain text, but any know how exactly it happen?

Tags: special-characters, symbols

♯
♭

I saw this two symbol and i copied it.
try to do any html entities or special character.. but i can't get any result
I can't find any information on google also because this is not a searchable symbols
any one can explain how this flat and sharp musical symbol exist in which standard?
and how to type or generate them and any siblings?

♯
♭
♪
♬
♫

Comment: The standard used to define the characters is [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard used to define the characters is [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

See [Unicode Miscellaneous Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols) (includes common music symbols like ♯) and [Unicode Musical Symbols](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf) (other music symbols) -- I did a search for "unicode musical symbols", there are many more hits.

Happy coding.

---

See [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) -- or use the [Windows Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map). However, you need to know the code-point (or general code-point area)
 :-) Other operating systems have different input methods and utilities.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search find the following page which lists entity codes for musical notes:

http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=music

Comment: +1 Very nice find. See [XHMTL5/HTML4 character entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215053/xhtml5-and-html4-character-entities) for some more background.

Answer (score 2):

It is in Unicode, and you can insert any Unicode character by putting this in HTML/xHTML markup:

```
&#x266C;
```

Gives `♬`, i.e. you put `&#x` and suffix it with the Hex code of the character (end it with `;`)

**P.S:** This technique is used as the last resort when facing character encoding problems.

Answer (score 1):

> explain how this flat and sharp musical symbol exist in which standard?

[Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf)

> and how to type or generate them and any siblings?

There are utilities for picking characters from unicode distributed with most operating systems.